# Swift: How to filter json data

Tags: arrays, string, swift, filter

if a `NSArray` data like this:

```
var arrayData:NSArray = [{name:"aaa",tel:"0000"},{name:"bbb",tel:"0000"}]
```

how do I filter `name = "aaa"`

thanks.

Comment: What are the `{ }` in the array literal representing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use the `filter` method in `Array`. The method takes a closure indicating whether to include the value in the new array. For example:

```
let array: NSArray = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
let fiteredArray = (array as! Array).filter { $0 != "aaa" }
```

`filteredArray` now only contains `"bbb"` and `"ccc"`.